# How I do I aggregate or perform calculations on a time datatype in "MM:SS:MS" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, aggregate, datatypes, time

I'm currently working on an NBA project and I need to take the average minutes played per player, but I have no idea how to aggregate or calculate the time datatype.

I know you have to convert it, but I have no idea what to covert it to.

For example: a value is 31:56:00, but when I use calculations on it, it becomes 315600 as an integer, instead of remaining as that datatype with minutes, seconds, milliseconds. I apologize if this has been answered, but I can't find any solutions online and I'm still learning the fundamentals of MySQL.

Edit:
Here's a screenshot of the data and I'll show what happens if I perform a calculation or an aggregate, it'll basically remove the colons and keep it as an integer, but I want it to remain in the same format.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `31:56:00` seems like an invalid format. Are you sure that's how it's stored?

Comment: That's what's on my table. I've extracted the data off basketball-reference.com and the data is set to minutes, seconds, milliseconds, but I can provide a screenshot cause I have no idea how to get around this

Comment: Please edit your question and post your query

Comment: Well MySQL has functions to extra each part of the time as an integer which you can then convert to the same appropriate unit of granularity for each. This would allow you to then correctly aggregate the total time in that unit, e.g. milliseconds. For example, `MINUTE(SomeTimeValue)` would get you the minutes, and `SECOND(SomeTimeValue)` for the seconds, etc. But I believe you would need the hours component of the time, which is why I think your data might be incorrectly formatted. What is the actual data type of it in the table, a string-based one?

Comment: Just added a couple screenshots to make it more clear

Comment: I put the datatype as TIME so maybe that's what's causing the issue. I know you can convert data types, but I'm not sure which one I would use to keep it the same. Maybe my datatype is incorrect.

Comment: I see what you mean actually, I didn't consider it to be HH:MM:SS, and assumed it was MM:SS:MS instead so I actually have my minutes as hours, seconds as minutes and milliseconds as seconds. But I don't know if that will resolve the calculations part

Comment: @thisisforfun Yes, that's what I mean. The `TIME` data type starts with `HH` not `MM`.

Comment: @J.D. is it possible to change this at all throughout the my tables without messing it all up? I was scraping on Excel and just didn't even question the datatype being literal TIME rather than a duration I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Store such values as strings (say, `VARCHAR(11)`), complete with colons, etc.  You will not be able to compare, sort, etc the values because of things like "9:00:00" > "10:00:00" because of the way strings work.  And subtract won't work even if you switch to ints 310000 because 310000-305900 gives the wrong answer.

Plan B:  Store the values as `TIME` values -- convert before inserting.  Now you can compare, sort, etc, the values.

Plan C:  In all your examples, the string ends with `:00`.  Remove that.

Your title mentions "MS" as if it is "milliseconds".  But there should be 3 digits for such??  State how you will deal with MS and I can help with the conversion needed (either before storing or when computing).

**More**

Plan D:  Is that 30-40 "minutes played" or "hours played"?  If it really is HH:MM:SS, then that is compatible with the `TIME` datatypes.  So, as long as it does not need to be to big a number, those strings will convert correctly into `TIME`.  `TIME` happy with compare, sorts, subtracts, etc.

Comment: I just assumed but you're right. It's HH:MM:SS and I didn't even realize it when I was scraping the data. I currently have it as TIME but I now I need to shift my hours to my minutes, minutes to my seconds to get it in the correct TIME datatype. Is that possible without messing up the entire column

Comment: I added Plan D.

Answer (score 0):

MAX() and MIN() can process either numeric or string arguments, they cannot process TIME arguments. When you use these functions over TIME literals / columns then the values are implicitly converted to compatible datatype. Due to TIME literals description the convertion to numeric value is preferred, and you obtain incorrect output.

Possible solution.

If your column datatype is VARCHAR and the amount of digits is fixed then your values are ready for MIN/MAX value selection. If your column datatype is TIME then you must convert it to string explicitly with CAST() or DATE_FORMAT() function.

Now you have two string values, and you need to substract them. You must convert them to TIME datatype and apply TIMEDIFF() function. If your source values were TIME and you convert them to standard TIME literal format then you may use them immediately, the server will convert them to TIME implicitly. If your source values are VARCHAR then you must convert them to TIME explicitly using STR_TO_DATE().

Finally.

For VARCHAR column:

```
TIMEDIFF( STR_TO_DATE(MAX(minutes_played), '%i:%s:%f'), 
          STR_TO_DATE(MIN(minutes_played), '%i:%s:%f') 
         )
```

For TIME column (assuming that the values were converted to TIME datatype correctly):

```
TIMEDIFF( MAX(CAST(minutes_played AS CHAR)), 
          MIN(CAST(minutes_played AS CHAR)) 
         )
```

Both variants returns the output in TIME format.

If you need the output in numeric format (the amount of seconds, for example) then use TIMESTAMPDIFF() function.

Comment: This does make sense but I should add: if my TIME is supposed to be a duration (31:56:00 was input correct but I wanted it to mean he played 31 minutes and 56 seconds of game time), do these concepts still apply. Or is the TIME just for literal clock time

Comment: @thisisforfun My code takes this into account. See the pattern used in STR_TO_DATE()... https://dbfiddle.uk/2elNiAMr